# jQuery FadeIn multiple Times

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

so I wrote the following code:

```
$('.frame').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(800).queue(function(){
            $('#box'+id).addClass('active').fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
});
```

So whenever a button with the frame class is clicked, it gets the corresponding box and fades it in... at least in theory. It works for the first time for every box, so I can click once through all of them and they all fade in correctly. But whenever I want to fade in one, i already faded in before (even if I clicked through all the others before), it won't fade in again. It still adds the active class, fades out the other one correctly and removes its active class, but it does not fade in.

As if this wouldn't be strange enough already, the code stops working as soon, as i provoke the above error. So to say, as soon as I try to fade in an object a second time and it won't, I can't fade in another one again, it does not even adds the active class any more (but stil removes the old one!)

hope you can help.

Comment: You don't need the `each` method. Use `$('.frame').click(function(e) {})` instead.

Comment: Can you add some HTML code or provide a fiddle? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.frame').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(800, function() {
        $('#box' + id).addClass('active').fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

If this does not work, provide your HTML or a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) please.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thanks a lot. :D Thought I had to apply the function to each button seperately, that's why I used the each-function. Good to know it works without too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.frame').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(800, function(){
            $('#box'+id).addClass('active').fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
});
```

That is, do not use `.queue()` after the `.fadeOut()`; instead put the anonymous function as a complete callback for `.fadeOut()`. According to the [`.queue()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-):

> *Note that when adding a function with `.queue()`, we should ensure that `.dequeue()` is eventually called so that the next function in line executes.*

So you *could* use `.queue()` but if you do so you would need to call `.dequeue()` from within the callback. No need to complicate things like that when `.fadeOut()` takes a callback.